# Can't write any characteristic using ANDROID BLE api

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, android-bluetooth, ibeacon-android

In my app I would like to write a few characteristics to a BLE device (iBeacon). The problem is that after I call `gatt.executeReliableWrite()` the beacon disconnects from my smartphone and `onConnectionStateChange` callback is called - `onReliableWriteCompleted` method is never called. Of course the characteristic is not written on the Beacon. So my question is - what am I doing wrong and how can I write characteristic to a BLE device using `executeRealiableWrite()` methodCallback methods:

```
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
                    mAlreadyConnected = true;
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                if (mWritingStarted) {
                    reconnectBeacon();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
            writeNextCharacteristic(mCurrentCharacteristic);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
            if (characteristic.getValue() != mCurrentValue) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    gatt.abortReliableWrite();
                } else {
                    gatt.abortReliableWrite(mBluetoothDevice);
                }
            } else {
                boolean result = gatt.executeReliableWrite();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReliableWriteCompleted(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onReliableWriteCompleted(gatt, status);
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                mCurrentCharacteristic++;
                writeNextCharacteristic(mCurrentCharacteristic);
            } else {
                //TODO: handle error
            }
        }
```

Other methods which I use to write characteristics:

```
private void connectBeacon() {
        mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        mBluetoothDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mMacAddress);
        mBluetoothGatt = mBluetoothDevice.connectGatt(mContext, false, mGattCallback);
    }

    private void reconnectBeacon() {
        mBluetoothGatt = mBluetoothDevice.connectGatt(mContext, false, mGattCallback);
    }

    private void writeNextCharacteristic(int characteristicPosition) {
        if (characteristicPosition < mCharacteristicsToWrite.size()) {
            UUID serviceUuid = mCharacteristicsToWrite.get(characteristicPosition).getServiceUuid();
            UUID characteristicUuid = mCharacteristicsToWrite.get(characteristicPosition).getCharacteristicUuid();
            byte[] value = mCharacteristicsToWrite.get(characteristicPosition).getValue();
            mCurrentValue = value;
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic gattCharacteristic = mBluetoothGatt.getService(serviceUuid).getCharacteristic(characteristicUuid);
            mBluetoothGatt.beginReliableWrite();
            gattCharacteristic.setValue(value);
            boolean status = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(gattCharacteristic);
            Log.d("Status: ", String.valueOf(status));
        } else {
            mWritingStarted = false;
            mBluetoothGatt.close();
            mCharacteristicWriteCallback.onAllCharacteristicsWritten();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible that the beacon is closing the connection?  Perhaps there is nothing wrong with the Android code at all.

Comment: @davidgyoung I've made some tests and this issue is connected with either Android or my particular device. Beacons disconnect from all apps I'd downloaded from Google Play and tried to use. On the same time the iOS app works OK. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: When you say "the iOS app works OK" what does that mean?  Are you able to use a different iOS app to connect to the beacon and write to the same GATT characteristic?  It would be helpful to edit your question to add this info.

Comment: @davidgyoung Yes. I can write the same characteristics using iOS app.

Comment: I am facing the similar problem, did you find the solution already?

Comment: @DinoTw Not really unfortunately.